# ImageButton image not resizing to smaller size

Tags: android, android-layout, button, android-imagebutton

This is my expected output image:

[image: output]

I have a grid layout of image buttons and individual image for each of the numbers and words shown in the output image.

[image]

I generated 9 patch images for all of them. Now when i use one of the images for a single button, with layout width and height set to wrap content, it displays too big as shown: (first one was using "src" attribute, second one using "background" attribute for the ImageButton.)

[image]
[image]

But when I specify some default height and width values such as 50 dp, the image becomes too small and the numerals are not even seen as shown below.

[image]

The layout code is

```
    <GridLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/numberGrid"
    android:layout_below="@+id/amountTextView"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="75dp"
    android:columnCount="3"
    android:rowCount="5"
    >
    <ImageButton android:text="1" />
    <ImageButton android:text="2" />
    <ImageButton android:text="3" />
    <ImageButton android:text="4" />
    <ImageButton android:text="5" />
    <ImageButton android:text="6" />
    <ImageButton android:text="7" />
    <ImageButton android:text="8" />
    <ImageButton android:text="9" />
    <ImageButton android:text="0" 
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:scaleType="center"
     android:src="@drawable/img_btn_0"
     />
    <ImageButton android:text="." />
    <ImageButton android:text="DEL" />
    <ImageButton android:text="CLEAR"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        />
    <ImageButton android:text="OK" />
</GridLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to specify some height and width in dp and set scale type to "centerCrop" instead of "center".

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:src="@drawable/img_btn_0"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
```